# ffmpeg keeps crashing while playing with ffserver. Can anyone fix this?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

So here's the deal. I'm running into multiple errors between ffmpeg and ffserver. The videos are in great shape, far as I can tell, and they stream fine, individually. But when I use a list, well, things get weird.

First, ffserver is running like this:

```
ffserver -f asfffserver.conf
```

asfffserver.conf looks like:

```
HTTPPort 8090
# bind to all IPs aliased or not
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
# max number of simultaneous clients
MaxClients 1000
# max bandwidth per-client (kb/s)
MaxBandwidth 10000

<Feed feed1.ffm>
  File /tmp/feed1.ffm
  FileMaxSize 700M
</Feed>

# ASF output - for media player classic
<Stream test.asf>
# the source feed
  Feed feed1.ffm
# the output stream format - ASF
  Format asf
  VideoCodec mpeg4
# this must match the ffmpeg -r argument
  VideoFrameRate 30
# generally leave this is a large number
  VideoBufferSize 100000
# another quality tweak
  VideoBitRate 768
# quality ranges - 1-31 (1 = best, 31 = worst)
  VideoQMin 1
  VideoQMax 5
  VideoSize 720x480
# this sets how many seconds in past to start
  PreRoll 0
# Audio Codec
  AudioCodec libmp3lame
  AudioBitRate 56
  AudioChannels 2
  AudioSampleRate 24000
</Stream>

<Stream stat.html>
  Format status
  ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Stream>
```

So then I run ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i dailylist.txt -c copy http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

The dailylist.txt file contains ([specs on those two are located here](http://pastebin.com/P1M7iKJK))

```
file /pathtomyvideo/shorts/0019.mp4
file /pathtomyvideo/shorts/0197.mp4
```

So ffmpeg runs perfectly, until a few seconds into the second video, when ffmpeg crashes with this message:

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer9.15 bitrate= 383.7kbits/s dup=5561 drop=11754 speed=10.8x
Error writing trailer of http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm: Connection reset by peerframe= 9755 fps=182 q=2.0 Lsize=   27156kB time=00:09:42.51 bitrate= 381.9kbits/s dup=5561 drop=11847 speed=10.9x
video:22639kB audio:3962kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.088314%
Conversion failed!
```

and ffserver says:

```
Assertion asf->packet_timestamp_end >= asf->packet_timestamp_start failed at /build/ffmpeg-e0CgSU/ffmpeg-2.8.4+git1~trusty/ffmpeg/libavformat/asfenc.c:777
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So. That's my problem. Any suggestions on fixing it? I can pastebin more detailed logs if they'll help, or run whatever tests you ask me to. If anyone can solve this, I'd be eternally grateful, and if/when this project launches, I'll mention you on-screen.

Thanks!